# Getting different inverse matrix when using Python and MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab

I'm working on migrating some code from MATLAB to Python but have found that Python is giving a different result from the inverse of a matrix, the correct one is obtained in MATLAB. I've just started working on Python so I don't know if i'm doing something wrong.

Here is the code for python:

in=

```
 import numpy as np

a = np.exp(120j * np.pi/180)
a2 = np.exp(240j * np.pi/180)
TS = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
            [1, a2, a],
            [1, a, a2]], dtype=np.complex)
TSi= np.linalg.inv(TS)
Ide= np.dot(TS, TSi)
print(TS)
print(TSi)
print(Ide)
```

out=

```
[[ 1. +0.j         1. +0.j         1. +0.j       ]
 [ 1. +0.j        -0.5-0.8660254j -0.5+0.8660254j]
 [ 1. +0.j        -0.5+0.8660254j -0.5-0.8660254j]]
[[ 0.33333333-2.33727800e-17j  0.33333333+5.55111512e-17j
   0.33333333+0.00000000e+00j]
 [ 0.33333333+0.00000000e+00j -0.16666667+2.88675135e-01j
  -0.16666667-2.88675135e-01j]
 [ 0.33333333+2.33727800e-17j -0.16666667-2.88675135e-01j
  -0.16666667+2.88675135e-01j]]
[[1.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j
  2.77555756e-17+0.00000000e+00j]
 [2.60178714e-17+4.14347263e-17j 1.00000000e+00-2.47902802e-18j
  1.11022302e-16-1.47851750e-17j]
 [6.65007139e-17+1.79729532e-17j 0.00000000e+00+8.50815013e-17j
  1.00000000e+00-5.85654397e-17j]]
[Finished in 0.233s]
```

For Matlab:
In =

```
a=1*exp(j*120*pi/180);
a2=1*exp(j*240*pi/180);
TS=[1 1 1;1 a2 a; 1 a a2]
TSinv=inv(TS)
Ide=TS*TSinv
```

Out =

```
TS =

   1.0000 + 0.0000i   1.0000 + 0.0000i   1.0000 + 0.0000i
   1.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.5000 - 0.8660i  -0.5000 + 0.8660i
   1.0000 + 0.0000i  -0.5000 + 0.8660i  -0.5000 - 0.8660i


TSinv =

   0.3333 - 0.0000i   0.3333 + 0.0000i   0.3333 + 0.0000i
   0.3333 + 0.0000i  -0.1667 + 0.2887i  -0.1667 - 0.2887i
   0.3333 + 0.0000i  -0.1667 - 0.2887i  -0.1667 + 0.2887i
Ide =

   1.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 - 0.0000i  -0.0000 - 0.0000i
   0.0000 + 0.0000i   1.0000 - 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i
   0.0000 - 0.0000i  -0.0000 + 0.0000i   1.0000 - 0.0000i
```

Comment: What's the difference? What's the result of `TS * TSi`?

Comment: Basically, 1e-17 is ignorable error. Note that it is not a rigorous math course, so very small rounding/numerical errors will occur all the time.

Comment: @ThomasSablik

[[1.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j
  2.77555756e-17+0.00000000e+00j]
 [2.60178714e-17+4.14347263e-17j 1.00000000e+00-2.47902802e-18j
  1.11022302e-16-1.47851750e-17j]
 [6.65007139e-17+1.79729532e-17j 0.00000000e+00+8.50815013e-17j
  1.00000000e+00-5.85654397e-17j]]
This is the result from np.dot(TS, TSi)

Comment: And what's the result of `TS * TSinv - eye(3)`

Comment: @Dani3850 That result is approximately `[[1 0 0] [0 1 0] [0 0 1]]`, which means `TSi` is correct. Matlab is probably just rounding the result to make it look better.

Comment: @ThomasSablik [[-0.66666667-2.33727800e-17j  0.33333333+5.55111512e-17j
   0.33333333+0.00000000e+00j]
 [ 0.33333333+0.00000000e+00j -0.66666667-8.32667268e-17j
   0.33333333+2.77555756e-17j]
 [ 0.33333333+2.33727800e-17j  0.33333333+2.77555756e-17j
  -0.66666667-8.32667268e-17j]]

Comment: Either you did something wrong or `TSinv` is not the inverse of `TS`. It should be nearly `0`. Your Matlab results are wrong.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Sorry i posted the results from Python, for Matlab TS* TSinv - eye(3) = 

   1.0e-15 *

   0.0000 + 0.0833i   0.0000 - 0.0555i  -0.0278 - 0.0555i
   0.0185 + 0.0413i   0.0000 - 0.0580i  -0.1110 + 0.0407i
   0.0185 - 0.0783i  -0.1110 + 0.0296i   0.0000 - 0.0031i

Comment: For me it looks like the Python results are better. Matlab's errors are about 8 * 10 ^ -17 and Python's errors are about 5 * 10 ^ -17. Matlab has bigger rounding errors.

Comment: I can see it now, thanks a lot, is there any way to make Python to round the results to zero? The results for the program im migrating get really wonky withouth zeros in the matrix.

Comment: Matlab is not rounding to zero. It has a different output format. You can change the format with [format](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html) and [print_options](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html). Try `np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)`